# NetSuite RestLet SHA 256 Authentication

Tags: vb.net, authentication, netsuite, sha256, restlet

I have an old running application. This application connect to Oracle NetSuite and send JSON data. It is written in VB.net and works fine. This application uses SHA1 to make authentication headers. I need to alter application to use SHA256 instead of SHA1. I tried Google and found few articles in python and C# but unfortunately there conversion in VB.net did not work here. Can someone kindly help to make this heading making process with SHA256 encryption. The current code is as below;

```
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    Dim url As New Uri("https://xxxxxx.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=999&deploy=1")
    Dim timestamp = OAuthBase.GenerateTimeStamp()
    Dim nonce = OAuthBase.GenerateNonce()
    Dim ckey = "01234" '//Consumer Key
    Dim csecret = "56789" '// Consumer Secret
    Dim tkey = "43210" '// Token ID
    Dim tsecret = "98765" '// Token Secret

    Dim Signature = OAuthBase.GenerateSignature(url, ckey, csecret, tkey, tsecret, "POST", timestamp, nonce)
    If (Signature.Contains("+")) Then
        Signature = Signature.Replace("+", "%3D")
    End If
    Dim header As String = "Authorization: OAuth "
    header += "oauth_signature=""" & Signature & ""","
    header += "oauth_version=""1.0"","
    header += "oauth_nonce=""" & nonce & ""","
    header += "oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA1"","
    header += "oauth_consumer_key=""" & ckey & ""","
    header += "oauth_token=""" & tkey & ""","
    header += "oauth_timestamp=""" & timestamp & ""","
    header += "realm=""xxxxxx"""
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to create header with SHA256 encryption. The above question creates header with SHA1 encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The publicly available documentation for the library you are using only creates signatures in SHA1

see https://developer.tracesmart.co.uk/smartlink/example/vbnet-oauth-library for the code

You could take that and adapt it to use SHA256

System.Security.Cryptography contains an SHA256 class so the work shouldn't be too effortful.

I made the SHA1 -> SHA256 change for my node based library with just two changes. Your effort should be relatively the same.